# PHP web service not working from jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, web-services, jquery

I have created Restful web service in jomsocial environment.
It's on the local machine.
When I test it using REST console it return's response.

local url formed is...

`http://localhost:5454/kisan-06/index.php?option=com_api&format=raw&app=users&resource=login&key=dfd8a84f8cdce807ae1d30a838415ea37eaa075c`

Problem:

When I call same using jQuery.ajax, always error callback function is getting called.

Ajax call is...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:5454/kisan-06/index.php?option=com_api&format=raw&app=users&resource=login&key=dfd8a84f8cdce807ae1d30a838415ea37eaa075c",
    data: "{ username: 'sai.kiks2@gmail.com', password: '123456'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache : false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("in success");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR,error, errorThrown){
        //alert("There was an error loggin in");
        alert("responseXML ",jqXHR.responseXML);
        alert("responseText: ",jqXHR.responseText);
        alert("errorThrown: ",errorThrown);
    }
});
```

I have a asp.net web service, which was returning response as...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string>{"UserID":"180339206","LogInName":"Amol Chakane","IsValid":"True","UserRoleID":"1","IsPending":"0","IsOrganization":"False"}</string>
```

Response from jomsocial web service is...

```
["UserID : 475", "LogInName : kruti patil", "IsValid : True", "UserRoleID : 1", "IsPending : 0", "IsOrganization : False"]
```

I searched for this issue, but couldn't find solution.
Please help me in this.

**Edit #1**

Tried to get response in other format.

```
{
"UserID": "475",
"LogInName": "kruti patil",
"IsValid": "Yes",
"UserRoleID": "1",
"IsPending": "NO",
"IsOrganization": "No",
```

}

Still it's not working :(

Thanks

Comment: And what do the vvalues of variables in the error section show?

Comment: What does your API return with that call (check in your console, in Chrome there's the Network tab that will tell you this), and what are the errors returned?

Comment: All values returned in error section are blank.
That's the reason I couldn't trace error. :(

Comment: Can you debug your php script? You can achive this if you print out the return values.

Comment: @reporter: when I am using REST console in Google chrome, I am getting desired response.
I am not getting why this is happening with jQuery ajax??

Comment: I remember having this exact problem when I used node.js within my PHP app through JQuery, for some reason there was some kind of clause that meant a different port acted like cross domain AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of search finally I found solution to this issue. :)

Instead of **localhost** need to use **10.0.2.2** this network address
coz android emulator doesn't recognize localhost
refer [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Now at least success callback is called

ajax call is..

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://10.0.2.2:5454/kisan-06/index.php?option=com_api&format=raw&app=users&resource=login&key=dfd8a84f8cdce807ae1d30a838415ea37eaa075c",
    data: {username: 'sai.kiks2@gmail.com', password: '123456'},
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert("in success");
    },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("There was an error loggin in");
        }
});
```

But now I am facing another problem...

How to access data returned in success callback?

Answer (score 0):

When you posted more information I **think** I found the/a reason for your trouble.
According [this](http://www.zuellich.de/tutorials/kurzeinfuehrung-json#wofuer) page the syntax of your json object is wrong. The linked page shows examples for the most common datatypes in Javascript. If you read the examples, take an eye of the position of quotation signs.

Comment: I changed my response to...

{

"UserID": "475", "LogInName": "kruti patil", "IsValid": "Yes", "UserRoleID": "1", "IsPending": "NO", "IsOrganization": "No", 
}

Still facing the same issue.

Comment: And what will happen if you don't use the hostname and the port number in parameter 'url'?

Comment: Then we reached a point where you have to provide the full html and php source code.