# How to call RESTful php web service using jQuery ajax?

Tags: php, web-services, rest, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP web service not working from jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037154/php-web-service-not-working-from-jquery-ajax)

I have created php web service on local envirnoment
url is:

```
http://localhost:5454/kisan-06/index.php?option=com_api&format=raw&app=users&resource=login&key=dfd8a84f8cdce807ae1d30a838415ea37eaa075c
```

I am calling this using jQuery.ajax in my android phonegap app.

Ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:5454/kisan-06/index.php?option=com_api&format=raw&app=users&resource=login&key=dfd8a84f8cdce807ae1d30a838415ea37eaa075c",
    data: "{ username: 'sai.kiks2@gmail.com', password: '123456'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache : false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("in success");
    },
    error: function(){
       alert("There was an error loggin in");
    }
});
```

Everytime error callback get's called and I can't trace the error. Please help me in this.

Comment: Replace your `error:function()` with `error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` and `alert()` the **textStatus** and **errorThrown** values. Tell us what those are. Also, press F12 in your browser, run your AJAX query, then go to the Network tab and tell us what error occurs there.

Comment: @Scotty implemented changes... **textStatus** =error and **errorThrown** = blank
in browser getting **Load cancelled** for index.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify a specific method in the URL which needs to be invoked on ajax call. I havent developed php web service, but in Asp we call like below.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MainContent_ButtonSearch").click(function () {
    /// hide employee details (if shown)
    $("#empDetails").hide("slow");
    var empId = $("#MainContent_TextBoxEmpId").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      **url: "EmployeeService.asmx/GetEmployeeById",**
      data: "{'employeeId': '" + empId.toString() + "'}",
      success: function (data) {
      $("#textId").html(data.d.ID);
      $("#textName").html(data.d.FullName);
      $("#textTitle").html(data.d.Title);
      $("#textDepartment").html(data.d.Department);
      /// show employee details
      $("#empDetails").show("slow");
   },
   error: function () {
    alert("Error calling the web service.");
   }
  });
  });
  });

    </script>
```

Comment: I had asp.net web service earlier. which was working fine. But now I have php web service. Which has problem.